# How to use LaTeX template for SIAM papers?

Tags: templates

I need to prepare a paper for SIAM. I downloaded the latest template from SIAM website--[`siamltex1213.zip`](http://www.siam.org/journals/tex/siamltex1213.zip) from http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php. I am using a Basic TexWorks to open the `docultex.tex`. However, there are two errors like:

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `pdfmark' (hyperref)
because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF  mode.

See the hyperref package documentation for explanation. 
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                  

l.3925 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

And also:

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: Use `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` rather than `pdflatex`.

Comment: Awesome! I tried dvi2pdf and ps2pdf and they worked! Thank you very much. Could you answer separately so I can pick up your answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` rather than `pdflatex`.

Comment: You can also use `latex -> dvipdf`.

Comment: How to write your answer  in code format , I am beginner

Answer (score 9):

This is new in the October 2013 version of the macros, which now include the `hyperref` package (but with the hard-coded drivers `pdfmark` and `dvips` -- which are synonymous, as far as I know). This makes the new version break with `pdflatex`.

If you would like to continue preparing your paper using `pdflatex`, you can change your local version of `siamltex1213.cls` by removing the `dvips` and `pdfmark` options from the `hyperref` call on line 797.

---

**EDIT:** This is now fixed in the latest update (January 2016) of [SIAM's macros](https://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php).