# siamltex1213 package TITLE

Tags: packages, titles

I am using Siamltex1213. The title it produces is capitalised.
Can one force parts of the title text to be written in Lowercase letters?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: Is `siamltex1213.cls` the same as the `siamltex.cls` found in `siamltex.zip` at http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siam? If not, can you provide a link to where the file(s) can be downloaded?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is use of `textcase` package with commands `\lowercase{...}`.

1. Further info can be found here [textcase](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange).
2. Test file and class files are from  [SIAM](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siam).
3. Also to compile, one needs to use Use latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf rather than pdflatex. Please see [SIAM compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183134/34618).

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{siamltex1213}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}

\title{This \lowercase{is} a test\thanks{This work was
supported by the Society for Industrial and Applied
Mathematics}}}

\author{TeX Production\thanks{Society for Industrial and
Applied Mathematics, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania.
(\email{tex@siam.org}). Questions, comments, or corrections
to this document may be directed to that email address.}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```