# No PDF bookmarks when using siamltex class

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I'm trying to modify the SIAM class to allow PDF bookmarks. Please use the following version of the class file: https://siam.org/journals/tex/siamltex.cls. Here is a sample code that fails to produce PDF bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{siamltex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\title{A Test of PDF Bookmarks}
\author{Jane Doe}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[99]
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Main Ideas}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Conclusions}
\lipsum[3]


\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is for submission to a journal, they will not let you make these kinds of modifications. If not, I wonder why you don't use a standard class but you need to load `hyperref`.

Comment: CFR: Good question. I am modifying the journal style for SIAM itself. My changes will become the new standard.

Comment: OK. Have you tried `hyperref`?

Comment: @tgkolda: Nice! Will this modification also take care of the problem with `pdflatex` in the current standard (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183134/how-to-use-latex-template-for-siam-papers/183150#183150)?

Comment: @cfr: Apologies - forgot the hyperref line, even with your previous comment. Fixed now. Still no bookmarks with siamltex, however.

Comment: @ChristianClason: Yes, this will definitely fix the problem with pdflatex!

Comment: @tgkolda: Excellent news! The problem could just be a missing `tocdepth` counter -- try adding the line `setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` somewhere in the class file.

Comment: That should be `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`, of course.

Comment: I just saw that that the updated macros are now [available](https://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php) -- great work (especially for supporting `pgfplots`)!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @ChristianClason, your suggestion worked.

I see now that this is essentially a duplicate of the following question:

[PDF bookmarks for sections and subsections with the llncs class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52387/pdf-bookmarks-for-sections-and-subsections-with-the-llncs-class?rq=1)

Here is the solution with the suggested extra line:

```
\documentclass{siamltex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\title{A Test of PDF Bookmarks}
\author{Jane Doe}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[99]
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Main Ideas}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Conclusions}
\lipsum[3]


\end{document}
```